# require error with mysql and Ruby. (windows)

Tags: mysql, ruby, infinidb

I have a problem to use `mysql` with Ruby 2.0.0 and Windows 7 64bits...

I have only : `require 'mysql'` in my script.

Errors :

```
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- mysql/mysql_api (LoadError)
    from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mysql-2.9.1-x86-mingw32/lib/mysql.rb:6:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mysql-2.9.1-x86-mingw32/lib/mysql.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `rescue in require'
    from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:144:in `require'
    from C:/5-recup_info/import.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from -e:1:in `load'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

And `Sucessfully installed mysql-2.9.1-x86-mingw32` but it doesn't work.

It's to use infiniDB.

I found a solution which doesn't work... `--platform=ruby` in command install.

Thank you.

Comment: Looks like it's missing the MySQL dynamic libraries. How did you install MySQL itself?

Comment: No, I've installed InfiniDB (which works with Mysql) it works but not with Ruby...
Do I have to install mysql 5 to use InfiniDB with ruby ?

Comment: You might need to unless InfiniDB comes with the right dynamic libraries. It needs specific DLL files to link in and they may be named differently with that DB.

Comment: I've succeed installing mysql2 with connector/C of mysql and to copy/past the dll..

Comment: You should post an answer with more details about the specific steps you took so someone in the same situation as you can learn from it.

Comment: http://blog.mmediasys.com/2011/07/07/installing-mysql-on-windows-7-x64-and-using-ruby-with-it/
"Time to install MySQL/Ruby bindings" part. But I use "gem install mysql2 [...] instead of use 'mysql'.